# Whitespace problems with string comparison

Tags: c, linux

I wrote a simple application which compare strings. My problem is with white spaces. Here's the sample code:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {  

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "go up")==0){
        printf("up up and away\n");
    } 

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "down")==0){
        printf("down you go\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now after compiling it with `gcc -o try try.c`, I run it in my terminal:

```
./try go up  // doesn't show anything
./try down //prints down you go
```

Is it possible to use white space in the Linux terminal?

Comment: The "Linux terminal" is probably `bash`, but I didn't tag it with that since it's hard to be sure. The gist of the answers is probably the same on any platform though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use white space from the Linux terminal.

Try the following:

```
./try "go up"
./try go\ up
```

For both cases, the system should respond as you expect it to.

The standard shell automatically splits the line into the `argv` array based on the white space. The quotes tell the parser to treat the text as a single string, allowing access to directories like "Program Files." The backslash escapes the space, telling the parser to treat it as a special character, not a whitespace for splitting the line.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you just have to escape it.  In your case the program sees "go up" as two arguments.

Try this:

```
./try go\ up
```

Comment: Thanks again it's my first time in linux and need to study it because of work issues.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to use white space in linux terminal?

Try quoting the space:

```
./try 'go up'
```

---

Side note: you should check `argc` before using anything in `argv`.

Comment: works great thanks a lot sir.. why is there a need in checking argc?

Comment: @lancerdude Well, the user is free to say `./try` without passing any arguments.

Comment: @lancerdude He is just suggesting that you make your program more robust and ensure that you have the proper amount of arguments that you expect so that you can exit or reattempt to get the needed data.